# function templates with class template typedef arguments

Tags: c++, function, templates, arguments, typedef

the following code is an example of something I'm trying to do in a large project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// standard template typedef workaround
template<typename T> struct myvar {typedef std::vector<T> Type;};

template<typename T>
T max(typename myvar<T>::Type& x)
// T max(std::vector<T>& x)
{
  T y;
  y=*x.begin();
  for( typename myvar<T>::Type::iterator it=x.begin(); it!=x.end(); ++it )
    if( *it>y ) 
      y=*it;
  return y;
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  myvar<int>::Type var(3);
  var[0]=3;
  var[1]=2;
  var[2]=4;
  std::cout << max(var) << std::endl;
  return 0; 
}
```

When I try to compile it I get:

```
>g++ delme.cpp -o delme
delme.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
delme.cpp:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘max(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’
```

However, if I comment out line 8 and uncomment line 9 it compiles properly and gives:

```
>g++ delme.cpp -o delme
>./delme 
4
```

Can someone please explain why the function template definition of max() using `typename myvar<T>::Type&` isn't considered as a match for `‘max(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’` and is there a way to get it to match without using the underlying `std::vector<T>&` type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deducing the enclosing type (or any attributes of the enclosing type) from its the nested type is impossible. It is one of the examples of so called *non-deduced context* in C++.

While the template function declaration itself is legal, you won't be able to call your function as mere `max(var)` since the template argument deduction cannot be carried out. In your case, the compiler will not be able to figure out that parameter `x` of type `std::vector<int>` implies that `T` is `myvar<int>`.

You'll always have to specify template arguments for `max` explicitly, as in

```
std::cout << max<int>(var) << std::endl;
```

How to work around this problem depends on what you were trying to achieve by introducing that enclosing `myvar` template.

Comment: I see, thanks.
The reason for the `myvar` template is to use column_major matrices in ublas without requiring the user to always specify this, i.e.,

namespace Cheb
{
  template<typename T>
    struct matrix {
      typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T,boost::numeric::ublas::column_major> type;
    };
}

I then want my functions to have arguments of type `Cheb::matrix<T>::type`. I don't have too many templated functions, so I can survive with specifying my template arguments explicitly, but it'd be nice to not have to.

Comment: If where Max() is called is also a template, can the parameters of that template be passed as the template parameters to Max() - would that resolve the type?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of coding this yourself have you considered using `std::max_element` instead? It takes a begin and end iterator and I believe does what you want here.

Comment: Thanks, but I was just using `max()` as an example. I have other functions where the same problem occurs. I will keep `std::max_element` in mind for next time I want a maximum though... :-)